# Got "RuntimeError: Unable to find a spec satisfying byebug (>= 0)" after modifying Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

I've created a new Rails application, then I ran `bundle`, and the bundle completed successfully. Then I modified the byebug entry from

`gem 'byebug', platform: :mri`

to

`gem 'byebug', platform: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]`

so that it works with Windows.

Then, I ran `bundle` again and I'm getting `RuntimeError: Unable to find a spec satisfying byebug (>= 0) in the set. Perhaps the lockfile is corrupted?`

Why does this happen and how can I solve it (not undoing the Gemfile modification)?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is any help to you, but the issue I had is that one of my gem's .gemspec had a duplicate dependency in it, like so:

```
spec.add_dependency 'rails', '~> 4.1'
spec.add_dependency 'rails'
```

Removing the duplicate fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this issue too. In the end I figured the issue was the difference of platform being used on development and staging/production.

To fix this issue try:

`bundle lock --add-platform ruby x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32`